# Docker with Django and Nginx container in the same network is giving time out in windows and was working before

Tags: windows, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Docker with 2 containers to run the Djando and other to run Nginx in the same network in my local Windows.

I'm developing this project since 3 months ago and was running perfectly.

But this week when i try to create a custom 404 page adding `handler404 = 'genericapp.views.handler404'` in `urls.py` the others pages of my application stoped and i removed this line code.

All pages except the `404 page` stopped and pages like  the "localhost:8080" started printing "504 Gateway Time-out":

[image]

When i access the log of nginx's container it's printed:

[image]

I check the docker-compose.yml and they are in the same network.

Below we have the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and the ngnix.conf files.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Ajustando TimeZone
ENV TZ=America/Fortaleza
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Fortaleza /etc/localtime
RUN echo "America/Fortaleza" > /etc/timezone

# set work directory
WORKDIR /belamarca

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm build-essential gettext default-libmysqlclient-dev libwebp-dev
RUN pip install gunicorn supervisor

# Instalando requirements
COPY ./belamarca/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  belamarca:
    build: .
    container_name: belamarca-app-hlg
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./belamarca:/belamarca
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    networks:
      - belamarca-hlg

  web:
    image: nginx:1.15
    container_name: belamarca-web-hlg
    volumes:
      - ./belamarca:/usr/src/belamarca
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - belamarca-hlg

networks:
  belamarca-hlg:
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  auto;
user nginx;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    client_max_body_size 8M;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server_tokens off;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
        #add_header X-Frame-Options: "deny; SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net; img-src 'self' http://localhost https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://themes.googleusercontent.com; frame-src https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com; object-src 'none'";                       

        error_log /dev/stdout debug;

        location / {
            proxy_hide_header Server;
            proxy_pass http://belamarca:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias   /usr/src/belamarca/static/;
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias   /usr/src/belamarca/media/;
        }
    }
}
```

Someone knows what happens and how to fix?

I already tryed to restart my machine and reinstall Docker but not solved this.

I checked the network and the containers are in the same and the Django container is running okay.

Comment: Connections between containers don't use `ports:`.  The `ports:` setting suggests that your application internally listens on the standard HTTP port 80; does removing the port number in the Nginx configuration help?

Comment: I think the port is not the problem because i was using this configuring in docker-compose has 3 months and was working. To check your sugestion i tryed to comment the "ports:" and not works.

Comment: From nginx pod try to `ping` to your django application. If it is working then try `curl` request. It will help you to narrow down your issue

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Before this problem I was trying to add a custom 404 page. And after change the urls with `handler404 = 'genericapp.views.handler404'` the error happened. So I removed this line code and after that I just could request the 404 page and pages of others routes stopped.

I don't know why but after build the project form zero everything worked again including the custom `handler404` page. The problem wasn't related with Docker, Nginx container or Django container.